# SQL equals like error

Tags: sql

I have a database consisting of header files. E.g: `<iostream>`,`<ctype.h>` etc. When my query is:

```
select * from hf_list where hf = '<iostream>'
```

it returns an empty set while

```
select * from hf_list where hf like '%<iostream>%'"
```

gets the correct result even though the entry does not have any extra characters other than <iostream>. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: This is not clear.  % is a wildcard character, so that will return all rows in your case.

Comment: are there spaces in the front or end of the string?

Comment: @OldProgrammer it would return all rows which contains `<iostream>`

Comment: @P_G I don't think there are. I tried the queries with spaces. Not working

Comment: Please add the tag for your DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Comment: Is it a `CHAR` column or `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying '%%' you are basically saying give me everything checkout below code

```
;with sam as (

select ' <iostream> ' as col1
union 
select 'sam' as col1
)

select * from sam where col1 like '%<iostream>%'
```

If you would like to check if you have blank data do this select * from hf_list where rtrim(ltrim(hf)) = 'iostream'

Comment: `select * from hf_list where trim(hf) = '<iostream>'`
This is what I entered and got an empty result set

Comment: You have modified you question, anyway if you add wild charector it will pull all the results which contain that data i.e if the data is sam and sama and you search for %M% then it will output both results but if you search with 'M' it will not return records

Comment: I know that but my data is <iostream>, no more no less. But still, searching with equals operator gives me an empty result set.

Comment: try length and see if it has spaces,can you print a result record here so that we all can see the record and also is it mysql or oracle or sql server